# Oracle Contcatenate output of a Cursor into a CLOB

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

I have a cursor which fetches records from a table.

```
open p_cursor for select a1, a2 from my_table;
```

Thereafter I use fetch to get the columns and put all of them into a single CLOB column as follows : ( add_to_clob is a procedure which concatenates a text into existing CLOB - my_clob )
fetch p_cursor into l_a1, l_a2;

```
  add_to_clob ( my_clob, l_a1 );
  add_to_clob ( my_clob, l_a2 );
```

Essentially - the output of fetch are being written into a large CLOB.

But the operation is running slower than expected; and we have millions of records to process.

Is there any way such that use of cursor can be avoided to that the process runs faster ?

Answer (score 0):

You can "cheat" a bit and use some XML aggregate functions like this:

```sql
DECLARE
  l_clob1 CLOB;
  l_clob2 CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT EXTRACT(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(COL1, ao.object_name||', ')), '/COL1/text()') AS CLOB),
         XMLSERIALIZE(CONTENT EXTRACT(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(COL2, ao.edition_name||', ')), '/COL2/text()') AS CLOB)
  INTO l_clob1, l_clob2
  FROM all_objects ao
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
END;
/
```

Just replace the simple query with your own.  Also, you'll need to